# using async and await in nodejs getting Promise { <pending> }

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

In my case , i am able to get the token but not the way i wanted ie i do not want to print promise pending and my output after running in tokenDisp.js is :

```
output: Promise { pending }

 t5Npxk5FfnRTj8iHd8vyyfGxnhXR4KQf
```

login.js:

```
  module.exports = async function doLogin() {
  const token = await loginToken();
  const myToken = JSON.parse(token);
  return console.log(myToken);
};
```

tokenDisp.js:

```
 const myToken = require('./login.js);
 myToken();
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: yes, an async function is guaranteed to return a Promise ... so, use promises .then method as intended - note, your `doLogin` function will return a Promise that will always resolve to `undefined`, of course

Comment: `myToken()` returns a promise. Is there a problem with that?

Comment: myToken() return promise <pending> with the token , but i just want the token

Comment: then, use `.then` like you would with any other promise - here's some [documentation on how to use Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) (in case you aren't aware, async/await is syntax sugar for promises, so promises is what you need to learn to use)

Comment: if i use .then , i need to export the function in another file and use it, is it possible ?

Comment: no, you don't, you need to use .then when you need to get the resolved value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `async` functions return a promise and you still have to use `.then()` or `await` on the return value from the `async` function in order to use that.  If you return a value from your `async` function, it will be the resolved value of the returned promise.  If you throw an exception, the exception will be the reason for the rejection of the returned promise.

The use of `await` inside the function is a convenience INSIDE the async function.  It does not magically make an asychronous operation into a synchronous one.  So, your function returns a promise.  To get the value out of it, use `.then()` on it.

```
module.exports = async function doLogin() {
  const token = await loginToken();
  const myToken = JSON.parse(token);
  console.log(myToken);
  return myToken;    // this will be resolved value of returned promise
};

const myToken = require('./login.js);
myToken().then(token => {
    // got token here
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

---

Note: your login.js module produces the same result as if it was written like this (without using `async` or `await`):

```
module.exports = function doLogin() {
  return loginToken().then(token => {
      const myToken = JSON.parse(token);
      console.log(myToken);
      return myToken;    // this will be resolved value of returned promise
  });
};
```