# sync way of using promises in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

loginTest() gives me resolve(value) so it goes to .then , my problem is since promise is async code, console.log(token) gets printed with promise-pending before promise fulfills.I want to display the value only after promise is fulfilled.Can any one help ?

```
 const token = loginTest().then(res => res).catch(err => err);
 console.log(token);
```

Comment: Already explained to you in your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267856/using-async-and-await-in-nodejs-getting-promise-pending from an hour ago.  You can never get the value directly out of a promise - NEVER.  You either use `await` or `.then()` to get the value.  Welcome to asynchronous programming in Javascript.  See the example in the accept answer to your previous question.  It's all right there.

Comment: It dint resolve my issue ....

 my usecase is i want to return token from getToken() async function which has await loginTest() too and export the module in another js file.After importing the module i am using function expression to store returned value from function to variable and printing that value gives me promise pending

Comment: You CAN'T return `token` directly - never.  Your function returns before `token` is even available.  You really need to read a lot more about how promises works.  You can NEVER get the value directly out of a promise.  You ALWAYS use `.then()` or `await`.  So you can't do `var token = loginTest();` and expect it to be your value.  If you do, token will just be the promise.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323).  You should really study that other answer.

Comment: `loginTest().then(token => { /* you can use token here  and only here */});`

Comment: There is no synchronous way of using promises.

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage [Async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function) / [Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) functionality:

```
const token = await loginTest()
console.log(token)
```

For Example:

```
async function getToken () {
  const token = await loginTest()
  console.log(token)
}

getToken()
```

You could also do the following for a "synchronous" [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) way:

```
loginTest()
  .then(res => res)  // Retained for example sake of chaining promises
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

This is assuming that `token` is `res`, adjust accordingly if it is an object and you need a child property :)!

Comment: const myToken = async function () {
  const myTok = await loginToken();
  return myTok;
};
console.log(myToken());

still i m getting promise pending as output

Comment: I have updated my answer with a more verbose example, let me know if you still get the issue :) @SrikanthTunuguntla

Comment: i m still getting an issue ...

my usecase is i want to return token from getToken() async function which has await loginTest() too and export the module in another js file.After importing the module i am using function expression to store returned value from function to variable and printing that value gives me promise pending

Comment: Would need to see your loginTest function to be able to help further, sounds like nested promises, un-resolved promises, or improperly implemented async await, you can easily do async await through imports, but if the promises are nested or never resolved you will have issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
loginTest().then(res => {
   console.log(res.token);
}).catch(err => err);
```

This presumes that the token is provided as a field of res. I don't know the structure of the response so you need to check that. Token will not be returned directly from `loginTest` if it is async.

Answer (score 1):

Use ES6's Async / Await.

`const token = await loginTest()`;

But please note that this line of code needs to be wrapped in a `async` function. Otherwise, await will not work. And note that await cannot be used in global scope.

For example:

```
async function getToken() { 
  const token = await loginTest();
  // this next line will execute after the result of of loginTest() returns
  console.log(token);
  // do something with token after this line
  const mutateToken = token + '123456';
}
```

Documentation of Async / Await found here: [Async / Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: my usecase is i want to return token from getToken() async function which has await loginTest() too and export the module in another js file.After importing the module i am using function expression to store returned value from function to variable and printing that value gives me promise pending

Comment: in that case, are you handling the returned promise object with a thenable?

Comment: using thenable i get the token perfectly but i want to store it in a variable and print syncronously , the problem comes like it prints before thenable executes as thenable is asyncronous

Comment: Yes, so (1) you can edit loginTest() func to add a thenable which returns the value of the token, or (2) add the thenable in const token = await loginTest().then(token => token);

Answer (score 0):

Try this promise :

```
var loginTest = new Promise(function 
(resolve, reject) {
    if (isLogin) {
        var login = {
            username: 'admin'
            //something that related with the loginTest..
        };
        resolve(login);
    } else {
        var reason = new Error('some errors..');
        reject(reason);
    }
})

loginTest
.then((fulfilled) => {
    console.log(fulfilled);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.message);
})
```

so, loginTest will be printed after fulfilled, then catch error if there are some errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access token by doing like below as it is an asyn method.

```
 const token = loginTest().then(res => res).catch(err => err);
 console.log(token);
```

Instead use below

```
loginTest().then(res => { 
   const token = res.token;
   // your further code goes here.
}).catch(err => err);
```